# Should I answer my own question in this particular case?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131137/drupal-8-field-api-vs-form-state) then kept on searching in the meantime, and found out there was a bug with API and it would be fixed. I stated this in one of my comments. Should I make it an answer?

Comment: Sure, why not. It will help those who stumble over the same thing. (Also, I think it's not necessary to  ask here on Meta; this looks like a   local issue, which meta.Drupal could address.)

Comment: I thought I'd post it here because it seems to be a SE issue.

Comment: @Kartagis nothing wrong asking here, all good. :-)